# The ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query is not updating but inserting new records

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called tbl_visitors

| id | vis_site_id | vis_at | vis_page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-04-27 19:29:11 | xxxxxxxxx |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-04-27 19:30:08 | xxxxxxxxx |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-03-27 19:30:17 | xxxxxxxxx |
| 4 | 9 | 2023-05-27 21:52:53 | xxxxxxxxx |
| 5 | 1 | 2023-04-27 19:30:51 | xxxxxxxxx |
| 6 | 1 | 2023-05-27 19:30:58 | xxxxxxxxx |
| etc | etc | etc | xxxxxxxxx |

I want to group the records in this table as month, year and site_id and write them in a table called tbl_visitors_montly

tbl_visitors_monthly

| id | vis_month | vis_year | total_visitors | vis_site_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2023 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2023 | 2 | 86 |
| 3 | 4 | 2023 | 408 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 2023 | 1 | 7 |
| 5 | 4 | 2023 | 1 | 8 |
| 6 | 4 | 2023 | 2 | 9 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc | etc |

id and vis_site_id are PRIMARY KEY in tbl_visitors_montly table.

The SQL query I wrote seems to be inserting new records all the time. What I want to achieve is that if there is a record for that site, month, and year, it should be updated, and if there is no record, a new record should be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_sys_sites_visitors_monthly (vis_month, vis_year, vis_total_visitors, vis_site_id) 
SELECT MONTH(vis_at) AS vis_month,
YEAR(vis_at) AS vis_year,
COUNT(*) AS total_visitors,
vis_site_id
FROM tbl_sys_sites_visitors
GROUP BY vis_month, vis_year, vis_site_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vis_total_visitors=VALUES(vis_total_visitors)
```

where am i doing wrong. How can I fix

Comment: Your id will never be duplicated, you could use only  vis_site_id as PK.

Comment: I don't understand. should i remove id from primary key in visitors_monthly table

Comment: i suppose you need unique index on month, year, vis_site_id

Comment: thanks Mate and Your Common Sense, fix it with composite key.